# Opening Home Folder in XFCE changes the XFCE desktop to Gnome

Tags: 11.10, xfce

I installed XFCE on Ubuntu 11.10.

I already had gnome-shell installed as I was previously using gnome 'classic'.

Now xfce works fine. But as soon as I open the Home Folder or any other folder for that matter, the xfce desktop changes to the gnome-one ( as in wallpaper and icons etc..). How can I stop this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using nautilus, and not thunar, use the `--no-desktop` option

```
nautilus --no-desktop $HOME
```

Thunar is the file manager normally used by XFCE, you might want to try it.

Comment: :( it did not work.

Comment: What are you opening your home folder with ? nautilus or thunar ?

Comment: I am not sure. I actually had to reinstall. I corrupted my installation while trying to fix it. Nevertheless, now that I think, it was probably the nautilus as I was opening the **Home** using **gnome-do**. Anyways, is there any configuration file or something that executes or loads up when either of the file managers start?

Answer (score 1):

I found a work-round for this issue:
I've moved the nautilus file to nautilus.real in the /usr/bin folder
Then i've created a new one name nautilus with the following content

`#!/bin/bash`

`nautilus.real --no-desktop`

Hope this works for you ....

Answer (score 0):

Using Nautilus with Xfce Desktop seems a tricky problem in itself for the moment. Even if it's not the default file explorer Nautilus will from time to time interfere with Xfce desktop, which is administered by Thunar. I think Nautilus+Xfce desktop is a bad marriage for the time being.